# Scrollable Div?

Tags: jquery, html, scripting

Does anyone know of a great jquery scrollable div (scrolls with window.scroll) that will only scroll within a div, i dont want to use position:fixed; as people have small browsers and might have it smaller than my div and cut it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you happened to try

```
div { overflow: scroll; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div class="scrolling"> 
 If I put too much content in this div such that it overflows it size, scrollbars will appear.
<div>

<style type="text/css"> 
  div.scrolling { height: 100px; width: 100px; overflow: auto; } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach has worked for me in the past.

```
.scrolly {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```